# Insert a string from eval-expression without the quotes

Tags: insert, eval-expression

I want to use <kbd>C-u M-:</kbd>, then `(format-time-string "%m/%d/%Y")` to insert a customized date string. But it is inserted into the current buffer with double quotes.

Any trick to remove these quotes?

Comment: Side note : I tend to use a zero argument instead of plain universal argument, to avoid ellipsis in case the return value is a (longish) list. OTOH a string is never truncated so it's not directly related to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than ask <kbd>M-:</kbd> to insert the output of the Elisp code, just write the Elisp code that inserts the text you want:

Try `M-: (insert (format-time-string "%m/%d/%Y")) RET`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not change <kbd>M-:</kbd> for this. I have setup <kbd>C-c +</kbd> to call the `vicarie/eval-replace-last-sexp` defined below. So, I just type `(format-time-string "%Y/%m/%d")` and do `C-c +`.

```
(defun vicarie/eval-last-sexp-and-do (f)
  "Eval the last sexp and call F on its value."
  (let ((standard-output (current-buffer))
        (value (eval-last-sexp nil)))
    (funcall f value)))


(defun vicarie/eval-print-last-sexp ()
    "Evaluate and print the last sexp on the same line."
  (interactive)
  (vicarie/eval-last-sexp-and-do (lambda (value)
                                   (insert (format " (= %s ) " value)))))

(defun vicarie/eval-replace-last-sexp ()
  "Evaluate and replace last sexp with its value."
  (interactive)
  (vicarie/eval-last-sexp-and-do (lambda (value)
                                   (backward-kill-sexp)
                                   (insert (format "%s" value)))))
```